# Multiple connect database dynamic from class deployment of repositories Spring project

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I need to connect to the database dynamically, where the database connection data can be passed by parameter, below is a sketch of how to make the connection and execution of the query.

*This sketch does not work. Show error when I execute.*

```java
 public class BaseMyRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable> extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements BaseMyRepository<T, ID> {

     private final EntityManager entityManager;

     public BaseMyRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
         super(entityInformation, entityManager);
         this.entityManager = entityManager;
     }

     @Transactional
     @Override
     public List<T> findCustomNativeQuery(String sqlQuery) {

         DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
         dataSource.setDriverClassName("org.firebirdsql.jdbc.FBDriver");
         dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:firebirdsql:172.16.0.251/3050:C:\\SisInfo\\delphi\\SINOVO.FIR");
         dataSource.setUsername("LOCALUSER");
         dataSource.setPassword("123456");

         HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendoAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();

         LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
         entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);
         entityManagerFactory.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendoAdapter);
         entityManagerFactory.setPackagesToScan("br.com.sisinfoweb");

         HashMap<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();
         properties.put("generateDdl", "true");
         properties.put("databasePlatform", "org.hibernate.dialect.FirebirdDialect");
         properties.put("showSql", "true");
         entityManagerFactory.setJpaPropertyMap(properties);

         EntityManager emng = entityManagerFactory.getObject().createEntityManager();

         List<T> lista = emng.createNativeQuery(sqlQuery, this.getDomainClass()).getResultList();

         return lista;
     }
 }
```

*Below is the error log that displays on the glassfish server.
This log is part of the `server.log` file*

```log4j
 Advertência:   StandardWrapperValve[dispatcher]: Servlet.service() for servlet dispatcher threw exception
 java.lang.NullPointerException
 at br.com.sisinfoweb.repository.BaseMyRepositoryImpl.findCustomNativeQuery(BaseMyRepositoryImpl.java:66)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
 at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489)
 at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
 at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
 at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
 at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy302.findCustomNativeQuery(Unknown Source)
 at br.com.sisinfoweb.service.BaseMyService.findCustomNativeQuery(BaseMyService.java:59)
 at br.com.sisinfoweb.controller.LoginController.login(LoginController.java:53)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
 at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:97)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
 at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
 at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
 at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
 at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
 at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
 at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

If you need more information just ask at will.

Comment: OK. What problem are you having?

Comment: This sketch posted not work. Show a error.

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you post the exception as well?

Comment: I edited the question and added the server log.